# UART Multiplexing

Tags: uart

I have an FT232R UART<->USB converter that I would like to allow to connect to two separate devices over UART.

Essentially, I'd like to have some way to "swap" the 2-wire UART lines on the FT232R from  my MCU to an embedded Bluetooth module on board, so can I can talk to both, one at a time, over USB. I know that I could achieve this with two physical switches (one for the RX lines and one for the TX lines), but I would like some way of doing it electrically so that my MCU can make the change.

Comment: Something like a 2:1 multiplexer and a 1:2 demultiplexer?

Comment: Are we talking about UART at TTL voltage levels? Simple tri-state buffers could do.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Yes, we are! That sounds perfect. Something like a TI CD74HCT125 should do the job, right?